# Convert one ascii art To a photo with python

Tags: python, ascii

I Want When One Ascii art Convert what I created with Python to a image output, And I do not know exactly what to do, Text to Ascii art I want to become a photo, thank you for your help and guidance...

```
from pyfiglet import figlet_format
from termcolor import colored

def Print_art(msg, color):
    Valid_colors = ("red", "green", "yellow", "blue", "magenta", "cyan", "white")

    if color not in Valid_colors:
        color = "magenta"
    ascii_art = figlet_format(msg)
    colored_ascii = colored(ascii_art, color=color)
    print(colored_ascii)


msg = input("what would you like to print? ")
color =  input("what color? ")

Print_art(msg, color)
```

Comment: Perhaps https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.multiline_text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something came to my mind now that I convert it to html and then download her photo (:
And do it with a flash drive to make the job easier for the user and more fun on the browser